# jQuery Get Image Dimensions, Apply To Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline-code

I want a div to get an inline style of the image it wraps around.

Pen here: http://codepen.io/stevenmorgan94/pen/xuEwm

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var img = $(".box > img");
$(".box").css({width:img.width(), height:img.height()});
```

So jquery get image dimensions, add inline style to .box with the width and height

Comment: Please include the actual code within the question.

Comment: CSS `.box{display:block}` and it will be the same size as the image inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jonathan didn't get it right. His solution not about what was asked. Correct one is

```
var img = $(".box > img");
$(".box").css({width:img.width(), height:img.height()});
```

Comment: Gugic my answer below was answered before Steven Morgan edited his question with code example above.. so to say my solution was not what was asked is wrong since the question was changed above after i posted my answer .. because you can see how part of my answer was used in his edited question

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your JavaScript requires jQuery

```
$(".box > img").css({width:250,height:250});
```

Using native JavaScript, but you need to give the image an ID

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myImgID');
myImg.style.height = '250px';
myImg.style.width = '250px';
```

**UPDATED AFTER QUESTION CHANGED ABOVE:**

@Gugic got the right answer above after question was edited :)