# jQuery, get each() img Dimensions apply to each() DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each

[jQuery Get Image Dimensions, Apply To Div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19729033/1616850)

Based on this post i want to add the .each() method to the function because i want to apply it on multiple DIVs. Couldnt comment because of too less reputation.

```
var img = $(".brand > img");
$( ".brand" ).each(function() {
$( this ).css({width:img.width(), height:img.height()});
});
```

This is what i got. How can i cache vars vor each case? Im a rookie... Sry

THANX FIRST 4 METHODS ARE WORKING !

Comment: "cache vars vor each case" not sure what you mean here?

Comment: Are the images present in your page on DOM ready, or are you loading them subsequently with Ajax?

Comment: I didnt now if you have to / can apply each to a var because the images have different sizes - yes, DOM ready!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css() method of queries applies to all elements of the selection, so your code could be better written as:

```
var img = $(".brand > img");
var w = img.width();
var h = img.height();
$(".brand").css({width: w, height: h});
```

**HOWEVER**
In case you wanted to give each `.brand` the size of the individual contained img:

```
$(".brand").each(function() {
    var brand = $(this);
    var img = brand.find("img").first();
    if (img.length) {
        // wait for the image to load or it might have no dimensions
        img.load(function() {
            brand.css("width", img.width()).css("height", img.height())
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u could do this:

```
var img = $(".brand > img"); //Possibly it's an array?
$( ".brand" ).each(function(index) {
    $( this ).css({width:img[index].width(), height:img[index].height()});
});
```

Or perhaps:

```
$( ".brand" ).each(function() {
    var img = $( this ).find('img');
    $( this ).css({width:img.width(), height:img.height()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment by Hubert, if you have more then one image per .brand container, the container will take the size of the last image in the container, and the code would run multiple times per .brand and might not make this solution the best one to use.

```
$(".brand > img").each(function () {
    $(this).parent().css({ width: this.width, height: this.height });
    // or
    // img.closest('div').css({ width: this.width, height: this.height }); if its not the direct parent you are after (the '.brand > img' however only finds images thats the first child to a .brand)
});
```

Comment: Note however that this will apply multiple times if there are more img in .brand and only the last image's dimensions are applied for good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, assuming that the images are present on DOM ready (not loaded later, with ajax), and with one image element per `.brand` element:

```
var images = $('.brand img').get();
$('.brand').css({
    'width' : function(i){
        return images[i].naturalWidth;
        /* or, if you're specifying an alternate width for the images:
        return images[i].width;
        */
},
    'height' : function(i){
        return images[i].naturalHeight;
        /* or, if you're specifying an alternate height for the images:
        return images[i].height;
        */
});
```

```js
var images = $('.brand img').get();
console.log(images);
$('.brand').css({
  'width': function(i) {
    return images[i].naturalWidth;
  },
  'height': function(i) {
    return images[i].naturalHeight;
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="brand">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="brand">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/140/200" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="brand">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/180/130" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="brand">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/130" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="brand">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/135" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight`/`HTMLImageElement.naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).